# What does the Centipede serum do?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

After

> Daisy

takes the Centipede serum during the battle with Talbot, that person is able to launch him into the air (and apparently into space?), something seemingly beyond those powers as demonstrated so far.

How did the serum enable this? It was described as being able to deliver some substance to an individual's cells. When mixed with the DNA of Daisy's mother, it would have healed (e.g. Coulson). If it had been mixed with the odium and somehow absorbed by Talbot, it would have possibly killed him. I'm not sure whether the DNA had already been mixed with the serum, but in any case neither of these seems to be what happened.

What does the Centipede serum do?  In particular, do we have any idea how it would be expected to affect someone based on how it worked in the past?

Comment: What *doesn’t* it do!

Comment: To the close voter: [In-Universe Explanations — Even Based On Real Science — Are On-Topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7367/19561).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was half-explained in one sentence earlier in the episode, when Simmons was showing it to Coulson:

> It's almost the same serum that was keeping Garrett alive.  Though the- Centipede ingredients might give you a little extra mojo.

The Centipede serum was meant to give enhanced strength to the user, but Garrett's body was so weak it only brought him up to normal strength.

Comment: Aaaah, that makes sense. It's simply that this was kind of dissimilar to what it did to Mike Peterson (he was made physically stronger), so I didn't think about it that way.